# Dataframe PANDAS Python format data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in dataframe in this format,

[image]

And I would like to have data in below format,
[image]

Can anybody please help how to get this format.

Comment: take a look at the `pivot` function, it will do what you need: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# create a demo sample
nan = np.nan
data = [{0: 'a', 1: 1.0, 2: 'g'},
 {0: 'b', 1: 2.0, 2: '7'},
 {0: 'c', 1: 3.0, 2: nan},
 {0: 'd', 1: 4.0, 2: nan},
 {0: 'e', 1: 5.0, 2: nan},
 {0: 'f', 1: 6.0, 2: nan},
 {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 {0: 'a', 1: 8.0, 2: 'g'},
 {0: 'b', 1: 9.0, 2: '14'},
 {0: 'c', 1: 10.0, 2: nan},
 {0: 'd', 1: 11.0, 2: nan},
 {0: 'e', 1: 12.0, 2: nan},
 {0: 'f', 1: 13.0, 2: nan}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

Create a group tag to target the records, then use `unstack` to turn `inner index` to columns.

```py
# set a record group tag
cond = df[0] == 'a'
df['tag'] = np.where(cond, 1, 0).cumsum()

# set column 0 as column name
dfn = (df.set_index(['tag', 0])[1].unstack()
    .dropna(how='all',axis=1))

# get column 2's value, with every group_tag's second row
dfn['g'] = df.groupby('tag').apply(lambda x: x[2].iloc[1])
```

result:

```
print(df)

          0     1    2  tag
    0     a   1.0    g    1
    1     b   2.0    7    1
    2     c   3.0  NaN    1
    3     d   4.0  NaN    1
    4     e   5.0  NaN    1
    5     f   6.0  NaN    1
    6   NaN   NaN  NaN    1
    7     a   8.0    g    2
    8     b   9.0   14    2
    9     c  10.0  NaN    2
    10    d  11.0  NaN    2
    11    e  12.0  NaN    2
    12    f  13.0  NaN    2

print(dfn)

    0      a    b     c     d     e     f   g
    tag                                      
    1    1.0  2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7
    2    8.0  9.0  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14
```

Comment: thank you so much Ferris, let me check this and get back.

Comment: you are genius!! Thank you !! I need to learn Pandas. any book can you suggest ?

Comment: Python for Data Analysis_2nd， by Wes McKinney

Answer (score 0):

The `pivot` function will do the job: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

You could define the index and columns based on your expected result:

```
df.pivot(index=["lev1", "lev2"], columns=["lev3"],values="values")
```

There are some useful examples on the link I shared. I hope this could resolve your problem.